# Add empty space between div's content and bottom border

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to add a bottom border to a div for the purpose of a navigation bar. The effect I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Currently, I have the following code:

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  
  $("a").removeClass("current");
  
  $(this).addClass("current");
  
  });
```

```css
.container {
}

.container .item {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 1px;
}

  .container .item a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 40px; 
  }

    .container .item a.current {
      border-bottom: 2px solid red;  
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="item">
    <a class="current" href="#">Page 1</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 2</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 3</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 4</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 5</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 6</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

I cannot find a way to add the empty space in between the content of the div and the bottom border without it being the same colour as the div background.

Comment: How about adding a white `border-bottom` and red `box-shadow`? Do you have any restrictions on that approach?

Comment: Pseudo-element would be my idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it currently stands you can't do this. You can't add a gap between an element and its own border. You can, however, add the border to its parent element (the `div.item` element in this case), then add `padding-bottom` to that same element to separate it from the `a` element:

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  
  $(".current").removeClass("current");
  
  $(this).parent().addClass("current");
  
  });
```

```css
.container {
}

.container .item {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 1px;
}

  .container .item a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 40px; 
  }

    .container .item.current {
      border-bottom: 2px solid red;  
      padding-bottom: 4px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="item current">
    <a href="#">Page 1</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 2</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 3</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 4</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 5</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 6</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Note that I've also modified your JavaScript to add this `.current` class to the `li` element and not the clicked `a` element.

Comment: I think this is the best solution.. since it is just modifying the already present layout without adding any elements  (_even pseudo_).

Comment: As seen from the answers there are multiple ways to achieve this effect and this answer doesn't seem to be providing any glaringly bad ideas. Would love to know the reason behind the down-vote. A justification of the downvote would help the community understand what is wrong.

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping to achieve, in a very efficient way. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wqkd62q5/)

new css:

```
.container {
}

.container .item {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 1px;
  border-bottom: 8px solid red;  
}

  .container .item a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 40px; 
          border-bottom: 4px solid white;  
  }

    .container .item a.current {
    }
```

Comment: This could use an explanation as to what's going on; code-only answers can be difficult to understand for people who needed to ask the question in the first place :-)

Answer (score 4):

One more version using `:after` pseudo element. Unlike other answers this will put white border *inside* of element, not push the green further outside.

The interesting parts I added/changed:

```
.container .item a {
    ...
    position: relative;
}
.container .item a.current:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

And here is a demo:

```js
$("a").click(function() {
    $("a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
});
```

```css
.container {
}
.container .item {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 1px;
}
.container .item a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
.container .item a.current {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
.container .item a.current:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">      
  <div class="item">
    <a class="current" href="#">Page 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/osajfgLc/

Comment: for me this is the best answer , just lacks a fiddle +1

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is what you want. Try this. I added a div with class box. This also can be done using css after method.

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  
  $("a").removeClass("current");
  
  $(this).addClass("current");
  
  });
```

```css
.container {
}

.container .item {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 1px;
}

  .container .item a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 40px; 
  }

    .box {
      margin-top:2px;
      height: 2px;
      background-color:red;  
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="item">
    <a class="current" href="#">Page 1</a>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 2</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 3</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 4</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 5</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Page 6</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
```